# Disabling OpenGeo's Dashboard

Tags: geoserver, boundless-suite

I have small problem with upgrading OpenGeo Suite from 4.0.2 to 4.1
Everything went smooth after updating. Exept dashboard.
I had OpenGeo's Geoserver installed on port 8180. And previous dashboard was starting also on 8180 (`http://localhost:8180`).
Latest version installed on port 8080. I changed port as before (C:\Program Files (x86)\Boundless\OpenGeo\jetty\start.ini). But my new dashboard is starting on port 8080. And previous one one port 8180.

My question is, how to "delete" previous dashboard and change new one's port?
Thanks in advance for answer.

Answer (score 1):

There was a 4.1 upgrade bug found that we are trying to address. Unfortunately I suggest you back up your existing configuration, uninstall previous versions and re-install 4.1.